# How to query the content workspace id in apex

Tags: content

How to query the content workspace id in apex?
As of now am hardcoding it.. Can someone suggest a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the ContentWorkspace standard object from Apex. I just created a library in my DE org, then, from the Developer Console, executed

```
List<ContentWorkspace> cwl = [select Id, Name, Description from ContentWorkspace];
for (ContentWorkspace cw : cwl) {
    System.debug(cw);
}
```

This gives me

```
10:41:02:058 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|ContentWorkspace:{Name=My Lib, Description=A library, Id=05850000000TX7XAAW}
```

Comment: Thanks metadaddy... My bad.. I checked it already but thought that this didnt work.. As it was returning an 18 character id that didnt work when i tried to assign it to FirstPublicationid of contentversion and it didnt work.. Just now realized that if it was 15 digit it would have worked..

Comment: How did you create this library? can you explain please?